# Increasing the rotation of an object with lerp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Goal:I have a 3 d button. Every time I click it I want it to rotate by 180 degrees on the X axis.

Explanation: it says "Turn 1" on one side and " Turn 2" on the other side. So I want it to flip on turns.

The script rotates the button but not by 180 degress, the degree of the rotation decreases with each click until the button is flipped and then it stops working.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong, I've read about vector3, quaternion and euler angles and I tried all the combinations I could think of. 
Another solution would be to use a flag and turn the button back by 180 degrees if it's been rotated already but I really want to understand why this doesn't work.

Here is my script:

```
public Quaternion newRotation;
public Quaternion oldRotation;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.transform.gameObject.name == "EndTurnButton")
            {
                oldRotation = hit.transform.rotation;
                newRotation = new Quaternion(oldRotation.x + 180, oldRotation.y, oldRotation.z, 0);
                hit.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(oldRotation, newRotation, Time.deltaTime * 0.1f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you mix quaternion elements with Euler angles. Construction of `newRotation` has to be done using [Quaternion.Euler](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html). So what you need is:

```
Vector3 newRotationAngles = oldRotation.eulerAngles;
newRotationAngles.x += 180;
newRotation = Quaternion.Euler (newRotationAngles);
```